# how to get 2 internet connections working

Tags: linux, tcp, interface

It's either I have a fundamental misunderstanding on how interfaces are suppose to work or I've done something oddly wrong.

I have two interfaces:

- `eno1: 10.6.59.203/24 (gateway 10.6.59.1)`
- `eno2: 192.168.5.100/24 (gateway 192.168.5.1)`

If I unplug one cable and reboot, regardless of cable, it will have internet.

However, if I have them both plugged in, only one interface works (defaults to `eno2`). For example:

```
ping google.com -I eno2   # works
ping google.com -I eno1   # hangs forever
```

**How do I get both statements above to work?**

**my /etc/network/interface**:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eno2
iface eno2 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

**my `route`**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.5.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
10.6.59.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
```

## Update

I found the way to fix this is `route add default gw 10.6.59.1 eno1`. However, how do I properly do this on start-up (possibly by just editing /etc/network/interfaces).

Furthermore, now that I have 2 default destinations, how does linux know which one to use by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one default gateway, thus outgoing packets will only be sent through that one; if you want to be able to use both connections, you need to manually add another default gateway (i.e. a route to `0.0.0.0`) using the other interface's gateway.

But please note that this will *not* use both connections at the same time; this is just not possible out of the box. One of the connections will be always used, the other one will only be used if the primary one fails; the preferred route is defined by the "metric" parameter.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. See my update, though

Comment: The preferred route is defined by the `metric`; the route with the lowest metric will be used, unless it's unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

By default linux routes outgoing packets **by destination address only**.
You need routing based on **destination and source addresses**.

https://superuser.com/questions/376667/how-to-route-only-specific-subnet-source-ip-to-a-particular-interface